# How to manage file unique IDs in c++

Tags: c++, uniqueidentifier

c++ (not c++11)

Say i have 100 .cpp files in my project, which currently do some work.
All of those files currently include some globals.h file which i can edit easily.

I want each of those files to have its own instance of some object, and I also want that instance to have some unique ID of the file in which it is instantiated.
In addition, I want those objects to be created by a factory method, and I need the instances to have some way for a user to handle them - meaning they can't be anonymous.

In short - I need a way to generate unique IDs for all of the files in my project, i need the file to be able to access its own ID using the same name in all files, but also to be able to access the ID of a file externally in another "manager" file.

Here are options that don't work:

1.
**Enum:**

If I use an enum and give every file an enum ID, now I can't do this in globals.h:

```
static thePrivateInstanceInThisFile = theFactory.makeInstance(fileID);
```

because I need a different `fileID` in every file, and that was defined statically, and uniquely named using my enum.

2.
**Class that counts its own instances**

Define in globals.h:

```
class FileIDGiver{
private:
   static int currentID;//initialize to 0 in cpp
   int myID;
public:
   FileIDGiver(){
      myID = currentID++;
   }
   int getFileID(){
       return myID;
   }
}

static FileIDGiver theFileId;

static thePrivateInstanceInThisFile = theFactory.makeInstance(theFileId.getFileID());
```

This will give an ID to each static file instace which is unique to the file, but now it is not manageable externally to the file.

I thought about doing something like

```
globals.cpp
int file1ID;
int file2ID;
...

globals.h
extern file1ID;
extern file2ID;
...

file1.cpp
file1ID = theFileId.getFileID();

file2.cpp
file2ID = theFileId.getFileID();

...
```

and whenever a user needs to manage a file he would either use the file's ID variable, or create a new one in the above manner.

This would allow me to access each uniquely and automatically file ID externally.
The only problem I have with this is the line `file1ID = theFileId.getFileID();` only executes in runtime, AFTER the line `static thePrivateInstanceInThisFile = theFactory.makeInstance(theFileId.getFileID());`.
which executes at compile time.

I can't figure out a good way to reverse this order, or maybe do a whole other mechanic.

Again - I need:

1. Automatically created file IDs
2. Unique file IDs (which are very very preferably numbers)
3. Usage of those IDs by the same variable name in all files (automatically, using a static variable definition in the globals.h file)
4. Ability to access a specific file ID manually by using another manually defined variable.

Please advise some good way to accomplish this

Thanks.

Comment: Call it C++03 or an older standard. C++11 *is* C++.

Comment: "i have 100 .cpp files in my project" you should probably be using a database. I don't understand what you are trying to do, but this is almost certainly the wrong way.

Comment: Could you use `__FILE__` as a unique id?

Comment: __FILE__ gets close, it generates a unique id at compile time. but then how would the user access the file from the "manager"?

Comment: @msw Looking back at this, after having failed the project, this is exactly the reason I failed. A database should have been used. I learned from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to access the static `Instance`s of other files, then this cannot be done via an automatically generated id because the id generated for a file could change each time a new file is added, or every time it is compiled, or even on each execution. Therefore in this solution, each file manually defines its own persistent id similarly to example 1 in the question.

---

ids.h

```
enum FileId
{
    File1, File2, File3
};
```

factory.h

```
#include "ids.h"
#include "instance.h"

class Factory
{
    // ...
public:
    Factory() {/*...*/}
    Instance createInstance(FileId fileid) {/*...*/}
};

Factory &getTheFactory();
```

factory.cpp

```
#include "factory.h"

Factory &getTheFactory()
{
    static Factory theFactory;
    return theFactory;
}
```

idmanager.h

```
#include "ids.h"
#include "instance.h"

template<FileId id>
struct Manager
{
    static Instance &getInstance(); // not defined
};
```

global.h

```
#include "idmanager.h"
#include "factory.h"

template <>
Instance &Manager<FILEID>::getInstance()
{
    static Instance theInstance = getTheFactory().getInstance(FILEID);
    return theInstance;
};

static Instance &getThisFileInstance()
{
    return Manager<FILEID>::getInstance();
}
```

Usage is as follows: for each file requiring a static `Instance` object, place at the start

```
#define FILEID File1   // The FileId corresponding to this file
#include "global.h"
```

Then in any file,

- The unique id is given by `FILEID`. (sorry it's a macro)
- The static `Instance` of this file is obtained by `getThisFileInstance()`.
- The static `Instance` of any file is obtained by `Manager<any_file_id>::getInstance()`.

---

This works by placing the implementation for an instantiation of the template `Manager<FileId>` in each file, each of which creates and returns that file's static `Instance`.

Advantages are persistence of ids, and zero run-time overhead: no need to dynamically assign ids, and the calls to `Manager<file_id>::getInstance()` are resolved at compile-time.

Also, the `ids.h` header can easily be generated by a script which scans the first line of each file for `#define FILEID fileid`, so the only maintenance left is remembering to write `#define FILEID fileid`.

Comment: Thank you!
This works just like I wanted!
Now all is left for me to do is make it work for template variables (not just Instance), and invoke setter methods on the local Insances, before each file runs.

Comment: Hi
I implemented this method of unique file IDs, and everything is perfect as expected.
Now, another requirement arises - What if 2 or more files need to have the same ID? or rather - 2 instances need to have the same ID?

Simply giving that same ID via FILEID fails due to double definition of getInstance().

I am considering one of the ways proposed here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48575/How-to-define-a-template-class-in-a-h-file-and-imp

but I would love to hear any better proposals, or some guidance

Thanks again

Comment: A quick kludge-workaround would be to surround the definition of `getInstance` with `#ifndef DUPLICATE_ID`, then `#define DUPLICATE_ID` in the relevant cpp files. However, a much more symmetrical way of doing things would be to manually define `getInstance` for each ID, in `global.cpp` or somewhere. But then you lose the automation compared to the other method.

Comment: I don't understand you, perhaps. If i do this, then still, the function would be defined multiple times, because in each cpp file, the relevant FILEID is defined for the first time, and then the function would be defines with the same signature in multiple files even with the macro protection. Did i fail to understand?

Comment: The idea was that for each cpp file having the same id, you place a `DUPLICATE_ID` macro in all but one, which then inhibits all but a single definition of the function. So multiple definitions aren't a problem.

Comment: I am having trouble with this.

Either I don't understand the usage, or this implementation doesn't allow it:

I need to have multiple instances of `Factory`.
`Manager` only exists once per file, thus getInstance() could only work for ONE such `Factory` - the one it is hardcoded bound to, through `getTheFactory`.

How would you suggest supporting multiple `Factory` instances?

The current way to create a new instance now would be to create a new `getTheFactory` method. but in order to get it to work with idManager, I would have to create a new IdManager.



Thank you once more

Comment: Hi
I added some functionality, and now I implemented this into my larger project, and problems arise.
Please give it a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329516/c03-linker-already-defined-symbol-doesnt-appear-on-intermediate-file

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a bad case of the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

Here is a solution which uniquely assigns integer ids to each file, then generates a unique `Instance` by calling a factory function with the file's id, while ensuring that the `Instance` factory is initialized  before its first use:

`idgiver.h`:

```
class IdGiver
{
    int id;
public:
    IdGiver() : id(0) {}
    int getId() {return id++;}
};

IdGiver &getTheIdGiver();
```

`idgiver.cpp`:

```
#include "idgiver.h"

IdGiver &getTheIdGiver()
{
    static IdGiver theIdGiver;
    return theIdGiver;
}
```

`factory.h`:

```
class Instance
{
    // ...
};

class Factory
{
    // ...
public:
    Factory() : {/*...*/}
    Instance getInstance(int id) {/*...*/}
};

Factory &getTheFactory();
```

`factory.cpp`:

```
#include "factory.h"

Factory &getTheFactory()
{
    static Factory theFactory;
    return theFactory;
}
```

`globals.h`:

```
#include "idgiver.h"
#include "factory.h"

static int      thisFileId       = getTheIdGiver().getId();
static Instance thisFileInstance = getTheFactory().getInstance(thisFileId);
```

Comment: Thanks!
You got my question, but I'm still missing one thing:
After what you did, I still need some external "manager" file that has access to the file IDs by name.
Something like
in file1.cpp
`int file1ID = getTheIdGiver().GetId();`
and `extern file1ID` in some included .h file.
Still, what ensures the file1ID to be instantiated in the correct order?

Comment: I give up; the only way I can think of for adding this requirement is so complicated, that it would be better just to define every file's instance in `global.cpp` in an `AllInstances` class, externing this in `global.h`, then writing at the top of each file something like 'Instance &this_file_instance = AllInstances.file_59_instance`.

Comment: Please share the way you can think about adding the requirement, even though it's complicated.
What makes sure in your way that the `this_file_instance` gets its value AFTER file_59_instance got its ID?
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You might modify your building procedure (e.g. your `Makefile`) to define some unique thing. E.g. you could compile your `foo23.cpp` file with something like (assuming [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) on some Linux system; adapt this to your compiler and OS and builder)

```
  g++ -Wall -c -DBASENAME="$(basename foo23.cpp)" -DUNIQUEID=23
```

<sup>You could get the 23 for `UNIQUEID` using some shell script or whatever, e.g. an ad-hoc rule in your `Makefile`. Details depend upon your file naming conventions.</sup>

then use appropriately `BASENAME` and `UNIQUEID` in your C or C++ code (perhaps with dirty `#if UNIQUEID==23` preprocessor tricks...).

So the idea is to **generate the `UNIQUEID` in your build system** and to **pass it thru some preprocessor symbols**. Details are OS, compiler, build-system specific.

You might also do some crude [meta-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) by generating some C or C++ source or header file (perhaps using some `awk` script or some [GPP](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP) or [m4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html) preprocessing) in your building procedure.